# For better performance, saving a path to a file or the file itself into the SQLite table?

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite

i am populating sqlite table via java JDBC, and the table is expeted to contain more than 500 million lines and it is structures as follows:

```
PK  NodeID  LAT    LNG    xmlFile
1   2342    33.4   21.34  c://city_0.xml
..  ...     ....   ....    ...........
```

and the purpose of that table is, to retrieve the `xmlFile` according to a given the `lat` and `lng`. and the `xmleFile "c://city_0.xml"` is saved on the hard drive.

and later i want to use that sqlite table in an App in Android.

my question is, since i would use that table in android App. for better performance and speed,

1- should i copy all these files `.xml` on Android device's SD card? or instead,

2-i should save the xml file itself `file.xml` in the sqlite table.

Note:

1-if case the first option is the better, there will be 600 .xml files with total size of 670 MB to be copied into Android#s SD card!!

2- all in all, i have only one table.

please advice?

Comment: 500 million lines and you want to use sqlite? 0_0

Comment: @e4c5 please let me know what do u suggest..thanks

Comment: 500 million records means a database that has to be carefully designed and planned and it will definitely not have any 'lite' in it.

Comment: @e4c5 which databse  u recommend using..kindly please advice..note that, i have to populate the table via java JDBC, and then use it in android...and all in all i have only one table

Comment: I have a friend that works with DBs for a living, will pass this question over to him, to hopefully help. : )

Comment: In my opinion there is a very basic problem in design if you want to store those sizes of data locally on an Android device.
Let's calculate with 2KB each file, so 500.000.000 files would mean like over 950 GB if I didn't calculate that wrong on-the-fly, so you a plannung to have 1GB of data storage on an Android device?

Comment: @Phiwa no, i have in total 600 xml files, and their size in total is 670 MB

Comment: Okay, still seems rather large to me, but you still got the problem with 500.000.000 records in a SQLite database which will not have the performance you might expect it to have.

Comment: @Phiwa so do u thingk saving only the file path in the table is better or saving the file itself to the table will yield better performance??please advice

Comment: Definitely the file path because on full table scans this is a lot faster, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Why don´t you build a webservice and request the xml files over http?
Storing 670 MB on a mobile device seems too large to me...

Comment: i havent thought about that solution, but do u think using webService would not cause delay in the data retrieval?

Comment: This depends on the webservice performance (nodejs would be great) and the quality of the internet connection, but I would give it a try